# Php и json, неккоректный вывод

Tags: php, json

Начал знакомиться с Json, код:

```
<?php 
$json_string='{"id":1,"name":"ivan","country":"Russia","office":["yandex"," management"]} ';
$obj=json_decode($json_string);
echo $obj->name; 
echo $obj->office[0]; 
?>
```

Выводит:

```
name; echo $obj->office[0]; ?>
```

не могу понять почему

Comment: У меня код отрабатывает штатно, у вас корректно настроен PHP?

Comment: Стандартно был вместе с Endels поставлен, до этого никаких нареканий не было

Comment: у вас не работает интерпретатор, скрипт отдается текстовым файлом наружу. всю часть от первой открывающей угловой скобки до первой закрывающей браузер считает за тег.

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос решён, после пары перезапусков локального сервера всё заработало

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.